# Ampersand in URL while parsing XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, url, ampersand

I have a problem. I parse XML. There is URL in that XML, that looks like this:

```
<link>http://basa.med-info.ru/xse/index.php?query=грипп&amp;cluster=9025</link>
```

When this link is parsed, using this code:

```
NodeList linkList = drugElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
            Element linkElement = (Element)linkList.item(0);
            NodeList textLinkList = linkElement.getChildNodes();
            link = textLinkList.item(0).getNodeValue().trim();
            Log.i(TAG, "link: "+link);
```

the result is this:

```
link: http://basa.med-info.ru/xse/index.php?query=грипп
```

So, for some reason the rest of URL is lost: &cluster=9025
How to solve it?

**Update** True code is this:

```
NodeList linkList = drugElement.getElementsByTagName("link");
            Element linkElement = (Element)linkList.item(0);
            NodeList textLinkList = linkElement.getChildNodes();
            link = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < textLinkList.getLength(); j++)
            {
                    link += textLinkList.item(j).getNodeValue();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "link: "+link);
```

Comment: escape it. http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/StringEscapeUtils.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
        link = textLinkList.item(0).getNodeValue().trim();
```

thus explicitly getting the text only from the first text node in your `<link>`.

Most likely the rest of the text is in successive items in `textLinkList`.